# Visit Visa Application

Tags: visas, uk

I am a British citizen and would like to bring my wife over on a visit visa so that she can ascertain whether or not she can be comfortable here.  My question is that if she comes on a visit Visa status will this affect us later when we apply for a spouse visa?

Comment: are you living together outside the UK or are you living in the UK?

Answer (score 1):

A good travel history shouldn't harm a spouse visa. There is some risk that a visit visa could be refused for a spouse because they think the couple intend to settle rather than visit.